# Marginpar does not appear in ledmac numbered text

Tags: marginpar, ledmac

For some reason my marginal notes don't appear. Is it because of line numbering?

```
% XeLaTeX can use any Mac OS X font. See the setromanfont command below.
% Input to XeLaTeX is full Unicode, so Unicode characters can be typed directly into the source.

% The next lines tell TeXShop to typeset with xelatex, and to open and save the source with Unicode encoding.

%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass[11pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{ledmac}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{adforn}
\pagestyle{myheadings}
\usepackage{hanging}
\textheight = 180.5 mm
\textwidth = 108.5 mm
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\makeatletter
% And in the paragraphed footnotes, I'd like no colon too:
\def\parafootfmt#1#2#3{%
  \normal@pars
  \parindent=0pt \parfillskip=0pt plus 1fil
  {\bf\printlines#1|}%
  {\select@lemmafont#1|#2}~%
  #3\penalty-10 }
\makeatother
\let\Afootfmt\parafootfmt

%\newcommand{\rhet}[2]{\edtext{#1}{\Afootnote{#2}}}
\newcommand{\rhet}[2]{\edtext{}{\Afootnote{#1~]\ \ #2}}}
\newcommand{\oed}[2]{\edtext{ #1}{\Bfootnote{] #2}}}
\footparagraph{A}
\footparagraph{B}













%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\raggedbottom


\newcommand*{\LeftWidth}{3.0cm}%
\newcommand*{\RightWidth}{\dimexpr\linewidth-\LeftWidth-2em\relax}%
\newcommand{\AlignedBrace}[2]{%
    \medskip\par\noindent%
    \parbox{\LeftWidth}{\raggedleft\textbf{#1}\strut~}%
    $\left\{~\parbox{\RightWidth}{\strut\textit{#2}\strut}\right.$%
}%


%\usepackage{geometry}                % See geometry.pdf to learn the layout options. There are lots.
%\geometry{a4paper}                   % ... or a4paper or a5paper or ... 
%\geometry{landscape}                % Activate for for rotated page geometry
%\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}    % Activate to begin paragraphs with an empty line rather than an indent
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\renewcommand %These two commands are for double-spacing
%\baselinestretch{2}

% Will Robertson's fontspec.sty can be used to simplify font choices.
% To experiment, open /Applications/Font Book to examine the fonts provided on Mac OS X,
% and change "Hoefler Text" to any of these choices.

\usepackage{fontspec,xltxtra,xunicode}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setromanfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Brill}
\setsansfont[Scale=MatchLowercase,Mapping=tex-text]{Gill Sans}
\setmonofont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Andale Mono}
\frenchspacing


\begin{document}

\beginnumbering
\pstart



NAture hath indued euery man, with
a certain eloquence, and also subtilitée \marginpar{Rhetorike
and Logike
giuen of nature.} to reason and discusse, 
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{document}
```

Comment: The log file is pretty clear: "Package ledmac Warning: You can't use \marginpar in numbered text on input line 92."

Answer (score 6):

Your example isn't very minimal, most of it is irrelevant to your problem.

But anyways, first: `ledmac` is deprecated, `eledmac` is recommended instead. Second, I'll quote the manual of `eledmac` (the same is valid for `ledmac`):

> The `\marginpar` command does not work in numbered text. Instead the
>   package provides for non-floating sidenotes in either margin.
>
> `\ledleftnote{text}` will put `text` into the left margin level with
>   where the command was issued. Similarly,
>   `\ledrightnote{text}` puts `text` in the right margin.
>   `\ledsidenote{text}` will put `text` into the margin specified
>   by the current setting of `\sidenotemargin{location}`. The permissable value for `location` is
>   one out of the list `left`, `right`, `inner`, or `outer`, for example
>   `\sidenotemargin{outer}`. The package’s default setting is
>   `\sidenotemargin{right}` to typeset `\ledsidenotes` in the right hand
>   margin. This is the opposite to the default margin for line numbers.

Hence, a working example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{eledmac}
\begin{document}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
Nsture hath indued euery man, with
a certain eloquence, and also subtilitée \ledsidenote{Rhetorike
and Logike
giuen of nature.} to reason and discusse, to reason and discusse \ldots
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{document}
```